# Laravel Authentication without registration and custom user retrieval

Tags: reactjs, laravel-7

I am creating a web application with React and Laravel. The problem i have is the following:

The company already has a database with the registered users. Now i am making a portal that needs to have a login but not a registration because that database already has the users. So, the problem is that i don't know how can i check in that company database if the data inserted in the form is valid and at the same time use that data with Auth::attempt to try to login.

If some of you can give me some lights i would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom UserProvider, [as detailed in the official documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers)

- Create a class implementing the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider` interface. Let's call it `CustomUserProvider`.
- Register it in your `AuthServiceProvider`:

```php
public function boot()
{
   $this->registerPolicies();

   Auth::provider('custom-provider', function ($app, array $config) {
      return new CustomUserProvider();
    });
}
```

- Update your `config/auth.php` configuration file:

```php
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'custom-provider',
    ],
],
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. But I didn't get it. It is my first project in Laravel and i'm getting some pains in the neck with this.

The point is that i need to somehow check the credentials in one database (that is already created and i cannot modify) and store the login data (email and generated token) in my project database if the Auth::attempt is succeded.

Comment: My answer describes the way to make `Auth::attempts` work without using the laravel-generated `users` table. I'm sorry if this is too hard for you, but you either do it this way or you do everything manually (losing the possibility to use the laravel `Auth::attempts` utilities)